# Where to register event listener for selected/deselected options of MULTI SELECT?

Tags: jquery, html, events, multi-select

For example I got a multi select box

```
<select id ="countries" name="countries" multiple="multiple">
<option value="1" selected="selected">America</option>
<option value="2">England</option>
<option value="3" selected="selected">Thailand</option>
</select>
```

Now I want to listen for event when option america is deselected  by user or  England get selected . Basically for selection and deselection of any options .

I am using Jquery . I tried .change but it does't solve the purpose .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following jquery for getting true or false value when item is select or deselect.

```
var aRes = $('#countries option').map(function() {
    return $(this).val() + ':' + $(this).is(':selected');
});
var frag = '';

for (var i = 0; i < aRes.length; i++) {
    frag += aRes[i] + ", ";
}

alert(frag); // frag return all true and false value based on select or deslect option.
```

see the following link http://jsfiddle.net/Bbuyu/22/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `.click(event)` and then checking the value with `event.target` ?

Comment: I am using chosen jquery plugin to decorate multi select and its no relaying click event like it do with change event .